# What is the meaning of $$ in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

```
irb(main):002:0> $$
=> 5052
```

What is the meaning of `$$` in Ruby and How/Where to use it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`$$` is the [process ID](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getpid.html). It's named that way to follow Perl, which in turn followed the Bourne shell; both of them also use `$$` in the same way.

Comment: @Wayne: Please feel free to write your own answer about the `English` synonyms, and perhaps link to it from a comment. :-)

Comment: If you rejected my edit because it was wrong or worsened your answer, I accept your rejection (but it would be good to know why).  If you rejected it because you consider your answer to belong to you alone, then: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/15843/141929

Comment: @WayneConrad Really, more because I dislike `English` than anything else. Part of my dislike is because: 1. it's only in `stdlib` and not in `core`, and seldom mentioned or used, and 2. `English`'s side effects in Perl (it reifies `$\``, `$&`, and `&'`, [with performance implications](http://perldoc.perl.org/English.html#PERFORMANCE)) has completely turned me off of it. (Granted, Ruby is not Perl, but old habits die hard.)

Comment: Chris, I don't share your biases, but in light of them, my edit was clearly intrusive.  Please accept my apology.

Answer (score 7):

[This](http://www.zenspider.com/Languages/Ruby/QuickRef.html#pseudo-variables) seems like a good reference for stuff like this...has a lot of symboly goodness.

Answer (score 6):

It's the process ID of the Ruby interpreter. $ is a prefix for global variables, see [here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Variable_Scope) for a list.

Answer (score 2):

```
pipe = IO.popen("")
if pipe
  STDERR.puts "In parent, child pid is #{pipe.pid}"
else
  STDERR.puts "In child, pid is #{$$}"
end
```

This example shows  how the process ID can be used. Process ID is part of 'Execution Environment Variables' (part of predifined variables).

Answer (score 1):

It's the process ID of the current Ruby process. Read-only