# Ruby on Rails writing ActiveJob sub-class logs to a desired file

Tags: logging, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activejob, ruby-2.3

**Ruby : 2.3.2**

**Rails: 5.0.0.1**

I have following classes

```
class JobA < ApplicationJob
  def perform(args)
    Rails.logger.debug "JobA log"

    if condition_1
      JobB.perform_later(args)
    else
      JobC.perform_later(args)
    end
  end
end

class JobB < ApplicationJob
  def perform(args)
    Rails.logger.debug "JobB log"
  end
end

class JobC < ApplicationJob
  def perform(args)
    Rails.logger.debug "JobC log"
  end
end

class RecurringJob
  def perform
    JobA.perform_later(args)
  end
end
```

I desire to redirect logs written by each of JobA, JobB, JobC classes to a desired file. However it is not working.

I tried following

**/config/initializers/logging.rb**

```
# Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44168717/936494
class SelectedJobsLogger
  LOG_FILE_PATH = Rails.root.join('log', 'selected_jobs.log')
  class << self
    cattr_accessor :logger
    delegate :debug, :info, :warn, :error, :fatal, :to => :logger
  end
end

module SelectedJobsLogHelpers
  LOGGER_CLAZZ = SelectedJobsLogger

  private

  def log_debug_message(msg)
    LOGGER_CLAZZ.debug(msg)
  end
end

SelectedJobsLogger.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(ActiveSupport::Logger.new(logger_clazz::LOG_FILE_PATH))
SelectedJobsLogger.logger.level = Rails.logger.level
```

And then updated my job classes in following manner

```
class JobA < ApplicationJob
  include SelectedJobsLogHelpers

  def perform(args)
    log_debug_message "JobA log"

    if condition_1
      JobB.perform_later(args)
    else
      JobC.perform_later(args)
    end
  end
end

class JobB < ApplicationJob
  include SelectedJobsLogHelpers

  def perform(args)
    log_debug_message "JobB log"
  end
end

class JobC < ApplicationJob
  include SelectedJobsLogHelpers

  def perform(args)
    log_debug_message "JobC log"
  end
end
```

With that in place only `"JobA log"` is getting written to `log/selected_jobs.log` and `JobB log` and `JobC log` are getting written to `log/development.log`

**log/selected_jobs.log**

```
# Logfile created on 2019-07-11 20:55:47 +0530 by logger.rb/56438
JobA log
```

**log/development.log**

```
[ActiveJob] Enqueued JobA (Job ID: cbdc5989-40a5-4dd9-8ade-b14ea85c0214) to Sidekiq(queue_1) with arguments: 63
[ActiveJob] [JobA] [cbdc5989-40a5-4dd9-8ade-b14ea85c0214] Performing JobA from Sidekiq(my_queue) with arguments: 63
[ActiveJob] [JobA] [cbdc5989-40a5-4dd9-8ade-b14ea85c0214] Enqueued JobB (Job ID: a1de8536-1cda-47b7-ba7e-7e3e913c58b3) to Sidekiq(queue_2) with arguments: 162
[ActiveJob] [JobA] [cbdc5989-40a5-4dd9-8ade-b14ea85c0214] Performed JobA from Sidekiq(my_queue) in 160.3ms
[ActiveJob] [JobB] [a1de8536-1cda-47b7-ba7e-7e3e913c58b3] Performing JobB from Sidekiq(queue_2) with arguments: 162
[ActiveJob] [JobB] [a1de8536-1cda-47b7-ba7e-7e3e913c58b3] JobB log
[ActiveJob] [JobB] [a1de8536-1cda-47b7-ba7e-7e3e913c58b3] Performed JobB from Sidekiq(queue_2) in 349.68ms

[ActiveJob] Enqueued JobA (Job ID: 90b1863e-4967-41d6-8ad9-a9a329df46e9) to Sidekiq(queue_1) with arguments: 63
[ActiveJob] [JobA] [90b1863e-4967-41d6-8ad9-a9a329df46e9] Performing JobA from Sidekiq(queue_1) with arguments: 63
....
...

[ActiveJob] [JobA] [90b1863e-4967-41d6-8ad9-a9a329df46e9] Performed JobA from Sidekiq(queue_1) in 13.21ms
```

Also as can be seen in **log/selected_jobs.log** the job logs are not written in the format like they are getting written in format **log/development.log**. I need the logs in former file to be written in the same format as they are in latter.

Can anybody please help me achieving the desired thing?